# Capture Entity argument to webtarget.request.put in with mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm trying to capture an argument passed to my webtarget. But IntelliJ keeps telling me it is wrong

aren't you able to capture the Entity.class or am I doing it wrong?

Code snippet

```
private WebTarget webTarget;

response = target.request("application/hal+json").put(Entity.entity(inputString, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));
```

My test

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ConnectorClientTest {

    @Mock
    WebTarget webTarget;

    @Mock
    Invocation.Builder builder;

    @InjectMocks
    ConnectorClient connectorClient;


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        Response response = null;
        when(webTarget.path(any())).thenReturn(webTarget);
        when(webTarget.path(any())).thenReturn(webTarget);
        when(webTarget.request(anyString())).thenReturn(builder);
        when(builder.put(any(Entity.class)))
            .thenReturn(response);
    }

        @Test
        public void initiatePropertyIdentifierSearchTest(){

        PropertyIdentifierSearchInput input = new 
        PropertyIdentifierSearchInput("12345670", BigInteger.valueOf(123));

        connectorClient.initiatePropertyIdentifierSearch(input);
        ArgumentCaptor<Entity> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Entity.class);
        verify(webTarget.request((String[]) 
        Mockito.any()).put(argument.capture()));
        Entity entity = argument.getValue();
        //assert the entity


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `verify` line is wrong. You have to verify the `builder`:

```
verify(builder).put(argument.capture());
```